# Does MySQL's JDBC driver have a facility for parsing SQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm writing a Java tool to validate SQL statements. For SELECT queries, I can do it with `Connection.prepareStatement` and `PreparedStatemet.getMetaData`. No exceptions == good query. Unfourtunately it doesn't work with eg. INSERT statements -- errors in query create exception only at executing the statement.

Is there a way to parse SQL via JDBC without executing the statement? An internal method maybe?

<del>Unfourtunately I was also unable to find source code for Connector/J -- I'd be grateful for links to it.</del>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found an answer myself, need to call a protected method:`com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.getInstance(MySQLConnection conn, String sql, String catalog, int, int)`